# Is there a way to state changes that will be applied to method parameters within Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

Imagine a method that applies changes to the parameterized objects. For example a map oder list passed.

If the developer decides not to create and return a copy of the parameter I guess it would be best to have a notice in the Javadoc of this method and the parameter which indicates these changes.

I could think of an alternate @param tag like @varparam or @refparam (Regarding pass-by-reference keywords of other programming languages).

The question is: Is there a common way to do those hints in Javadoc? How common is it to apply changes to parameters? I guess this could be a problem that appears often.

Comment: If you don't have code that will morph itself somehow during run time, then I don't see why current tags and options are not enough for you?

Comment: @Tadija Bagarić The Problem is that it can be easily overseen, that changes are appied to a parameter. A reason can be just bad code. As a hotfix it may be better for the project to adjust the Javadoc than start doing a refactoring to eliminate such a bad method behaviour.

Comment: On  a similar note, around 20 years ago I proposed an `@unstable` tag which would work similarly to the `@deprecated` tag, but it was rejected. It would have flagged an API as still under development and warned there may be breaking changes in the future. But they were quite resistant to adding additional tags once they were set.

Comment: @Alvin Thompspn As your answer notices there are some methods, which use this behaviour with some reason. And some programming styles maybe use it in a senseful way. But I guess it would be a win to have a common way to note it in Javadoc. Thats why I asked if there is such a common way - maybe in any OS-Projects or maybe I missed a tag in my research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special tag that denotes this; the accepted practice is to clearly state that the method modifies the parameter object in the description section.

Although some don't like this style of code, there are some common methods in java core that do this. `java.util.Arrays.sort` (and a similar method in `Collections`) come to mind.